# Pass object or objects id to new activity

Tags: android, design-patterns, architecture

If I have a list of certain items (let's say fruits) in one activity. Here the items are completely loaded from a ROOM database.
Clicking on a `Fruit` should take you to the `FruitDetailPage`. Ofcourse I have to pass the `Fruit` to the new activity with an `Intent`.

But what would be better to do?

- Pass the complete fruit object
- Pass the `fruit_id` and reload the fruit object from the database in the new activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass object will be better, because the bundle has a size limit, therefore, as the fields of the object increase, you can catch errors. You will also need to keep less space in memory.And most importantly, you do not have to write extra code and inherit your object from Parcelabe.

Comment: You probably mean pass object id instead of object, right?

Answer (score 0):

In your list activity:

```
int fruitId = 5;
Intent i = new Intent(this/*activity*/, FruitDetailPage.class);
i.putExtra("fruit_id", fruitId);
startActivity(i);
```

In your FruitDetailPage activity:

```
void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
  super.onCreate(bundle);
  int fruitId = getIntent().getIntExtra("fruit_id", -1);
}
```